# Print string and formatted variable

Tags: fortran

Consider the following program

```
program foo
    implicit none
    real :: pi
    pi = 3.1415923
    print*, "The value of pi is", pi
end program foo
```

This gives the output as

```
The value of pi is 3.1415923
```

But I want the variable to be displayed only up to 2 decimal places, so I tried

```
print'(f4.2)', "The value of pi is", pi
```

This throws me an error.

```
Fortran runtime error: Expected REAL for item 1 in formatted transfer, got CHARACTER                                                                                                                                       
(f4.2)
```

How do I achieve the following output

```
The value of pi is 3.14
```

Comment: It is always good to show the error and not just write *"an error"*. If you want your self-answered question to be helpful to others you want them to be able to search for the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved the desired output with the following

```
write(*,"(A)",advance="no") "The value of pi is " 
write(*,'(f4.2)') pi
```

or with `print` as (thanks to high performance Mark)

```
print'(a,f5.2)', "The value of pi is", pi
```

Comment: Or `write(*,'(a,f4.2)') "The value of pi is ", pi`